# SQL Server 2008 : update multiple columns in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

Maybe my original post was little messy, so I didn't get much help. I updated my trigger with the `AuditTest` table.... Please see if you can help.

I am very new to triggers and trying to put together an audit table where it tracks the value changes on certain columns.

I have a lot of columns like: `Qty, UnitSell, Discount, ProductName` ...etc. This code below seems to work, which detects the `Qty` or `UnitSell` value changes, then do the `INSERT INTO` the audit table (now I just named it as `TEST1`)

If I would keep repeating the `IF UPDATE(FieldName)` statement for other columns, I think it will work, but it is too cumbersome in which keep repeating the same codes.

Is that way to optimize this, so I don't have to repeating the same `IF UPDATE (Fieldname)` statement?

```
alter TRIGGER trigger_Test_AfterUpdate 
ON [dbo].ERP_QuoteDetail 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    declare @QuoteDetailID int; 
    select @QuoteDetailID = i.QuoteDetailID from inserted i;  

    --- Updating QTY if old/new value change
    DECLARE @iQty int; SELECT @iQty = i.Qty from inserted i; 
    DECLARE @dQty int; SELECT @dQty = d.Qty from deleted d; 

    if update(QTY) and exists (select * from deleted d WHERE Qty <> @iQty) 
    BEGIN
        -- Insert into the audit table
        insert into AuditTest (
                [Type]
               ,[TableName]
               ,[PKCol]
               ,[PK]
               ,[FieldName]
               ,[OldValue]
               ,[NewValue]
               ,[UpdateDate]
               ,[DBUsername]
               ,[UserID]
               ) 
        values('u'
                , 'Table_QuoteDetail'
               , 'QuoteDetail'
               , @QuoteDetailID
               , 'QTY'
               , @dQty
               , @iQty
               , GETDATE()
               , '123'
               , '456'             
                );

        PRINT 'AFTER UPDATE Trigger fired.'
    END

--- Updating QTY if old/new value change
DECLARE @iUnitSell int; SELECT @iUnitSell = i.UnitSell from inserted i;
DECLARE @dUnitSell int; SELECT @dUnitSell = d.Qty from deleted d; 
if update(UnitSell) and exists (select * from deleted d
         WHERE UnitSell <> @iUnitSell ) 
    BEGIN

        -- Insert into the audit table
        insert into AuditTest (
                [Type]
               ,[TableName]
               ,[PKCol]
               ,[PK]
               ,[FieldName]
               ,[OldValue]
               ,[NewValue]
               ,[UpdateDate]
               ,[DBUsername]
               ,[UserID]
               ) 
        values('u'
                , 'Table_QuoteDetail'
               , 'QuoteDetail'
               , @QuoteDetailID
               , 'UnitSell'
               , @dUnitSell
               , @iUnitSell
               , GETDATE()
               , '123'
               , '456'             
                );

        PRINT 'AFTER UPDATE Trigger fired.'
    END
GO
```

Comment: In its current state your trigger works under assumption that only one row is being updated at a time, which most likely won't be always the case. SQL Server triggers are statement not row based, therefore you have to accommodate for that your trigger.

Comment: Can you explain how would you like to see your change log table?

Comment: @peterm, I have updated the log table looks like as your request. thanks!

Comment: I updated my post, please see if you can help.  thanks

Comment: Used Columns_Updated() -- Please see this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx it might help you

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using the Change Data Capture feature of SQL Server for auditing. CDC stores a record of all inserted, updated and deleted rows for whichever tables have CDC enabled. This will effectively replace the need for triggers in your case.

Details on how to enable and configure CDC can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this.  One question, can CDC take passing parameters sending from the page? like stored procedure?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to pass parameters to CDC. CDC makes use of the Transaction Log to identify that a change has been made to table, and accordingly updates the change tracking table with appropriate data and metadata.

Comment: Thanks for response, this might not be a solution for me because I need to capture the Session("UserID") From the application.

Comment: No worries. Perhaps you can get a better answer from other posters here :)

Answer (score 0):

Your fundamental flaw is that you seem to expect the trigger to be fired **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case in SQL Server. Instead, the trigger fires **once per statement**, and the pseudo table `Deleted` might contain **multiple rows**.

Given that that table might contain multiple rows - which one do you expect will be selected here??

```
select @QuoteDetailID = i.QuoteDetailID from inserted i;
```

It's undefined - you might get the values from arbitrary rows in `Inserted`.

You need to rewrite your entire trigger with the knowledge that the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables **WILL** contain multiple rows. You need to work with set-based operations - don't expect just a single row in `Deleted` or `Inserted` !

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, I will research more about inserted and deleted pseudo tables.  One quick question, is there a way to display all the data looks like in the inserted and deleted table after an event like update/delete?  I tried "select * from inserted" and getting 'invalid object' error.

Comment: @Milacay: those pseudo tables are only valid **inside** the trigger

Comment: i see. the single update statement run fast with the trigger, but 50 update statements cause pretty slow response. any suggestion?

Comment: @Milacay: not sure what you mean; if you've updated 50 rows, you need to do 50 updates - one way or another..... no?

Comment: I mean, with the trigger I posted running, when I have one update statement like "Update Table SET Qty = 1 where ID = 123", it runs fast. But if I have 50 update statements with different ID, it seems very slow. However, if I disable the trigger, that 50 updates run much fast. So, trigger makes the update procress slow significantly. thanks.

Comment: @Milacay: yes, the trigger will run after your update, and if you're doing way too much processing and fiddling inside your trigger, it will be slow. That's why I keep preaching: the trigger should be **really small** and ***NOT*** do a lot of processing! The trigger should make a note of something that needs to be done (e.g. write into a table etc.) - but NOTHING more! Then a second, async process (e.g. a SQL Server job or something) should do the actual processing, if needed.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s: I am still learning... What would you suggest for me to research for logging purpose if I have a scenario that some time I have more than 50 records updated, and I do want to capture the old/new value and userID session from the application?

Comment: @Milacay: try to use existing features - like the Change Data Capture in SQL Server 2008 and newer. Don't reinvent the wheel yourself - Microsoft has done a lot of those things already, for you - you can just go and use them!